# HelloSign API PHP-Error When Converting PDF

Tags: php, api

I am not able to upload my generated pdf into `hellosign` both manually and using API key.It throws some error when converting the pdf.

If i save a copy using the `AdobeDc` means i get uploaded.
Can you guys please help me for the problem.
Here is my code

```
<?php
//include_once("hellosign\library\HelloSign");
//include 'C:\xampp\htdocs\test_sign\hellosign\library\HelloSign\Client';
include_once("hellosign/library/HelloSign/Client.php");
include_once("hellosign/library/HelloSign/SignatureRequest.php");
$client = new HelloSign\Client('API KEY');
$request = new HelloSign\SignatureRequest;
$request->enableTestMode(true);
$request->setTitle('Su test by API');
$request->setSubject('Testing by using API');
$request->setMessage('Please sign this Doc,Let me know if you have any questions.');
$request->addSigner('mailid', 'Subject');
//path of file located 
$path="C:/xampp/htdocs/projectfolder/filename";
$request->addFile($path);      
$response = $client->sendSignatureRequest($request);
var_dump($response);
print_r($response->signature_request_id);        
?>
```

I have addded the API key in the API field,And i gave the generated file path in the addfile($path);

Answer (score 0):

This is Alex from HelloSign API Support. Please write in to apisupport@hellosign.com with:

1. a copy of the PDF that's giving you the conversion error
2. which program you're using to create the PDF (it sounds like you're saying if you save a copy using AdobeDc, it will work, so I'm assuming you're using another program initially to create the PDF)
3. the signature_request_id of one of your attempts where you received the conversion error